# node js request-promise, retry request on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

so I have a chain of request that are sent, and once catch at the end, the problem is if I have an error i wanna retry that specific request that caught the error, I know one solution to this would be to add a catch at the end off all the request i send, and when it catches an error it retries that request, but that would lead to too many catch statements, I just want one catch statement at the end that when it catches an error it retrys the specific request

```
rp.get('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/products/' + variant, options2)
    .then((data) => {
     // doo stuff with request
        return rp.post('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/bags/' + bagId + '/items', options2)
    })


    .then((data) => {
    // doo stuff with request
    })


    .catch((error) => {

    })
```

Comment: `I just want one catch statement at the end that when it catches an error it retrys the specific request` what's stopping you? that's how promise chains usually look

Comment: @JaromandaX the problem is i have multiple request that run after each other, so if i have a catch statement at the end and i want to restart the specific request that failed idk how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Your example indicates that some requests depend on the response of a previous request. Adding a catch handler at the end of the promise chain would make it extremely difficult to retry the request and continue with subsequent requests. You need to handle the error at the request, not at the end of the promise chain. This is pretty simple to do if you wrap up the request in a helper method.

```
function request(opts) {
    return rp(opts).catch(() => request(opts));
}

request({url: 'https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/products/' + variant, ...options2})
    .then((data) => {
        // doo stuff with request
        return request({method: 'POST', url: 'https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/bags/' + bagId + '/items', ...options2});
    })
    .then((data) => {
        // doo stuff with request
    })
    .catch((error) => {

    });
```

It's not really clear what `options2` is and why you use it as the request body in the second request, so this may not work exactly as you would expect, but the parameters passed into `request` can be tweaked to fit your use case. This will also result in an infinite request loop if the request always fails, you should implement some basic error handling to avoid this infinite loop (e.g., only retry X number of times, or retry only when you get a specific error, etc.)

Comment: That's exactly what I would do .... with safeguards against infinite recursion as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to design your `rp.get()` function in a way such that somehow whenever there is an error, the error object must have an identifier (stored as `type` key) as of from which request the error is propagated, then on a conditional basis, you can handle the error in a single `catch()` block accordingly.

```
const rpWrapper = (type) => { //add other required params
  rp.get() //pass required params
    .then( (res) => result )
    .catch( (err) =>  { throw { type, err }) }
}
```

Then, modify your original code to something like,

```
rpWrapper.get('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/products/' + variant, options2)
.then((data) => {
 // doo stuff with request
    return rpWrapper.post('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/bags/' + bagId + '/items', options2)
})
.then((data) => {
// doo stuff with request
})
.catch((error) => {
   if(error.type === "request1") { //handle error on first req }
   if(error.type === "request2") { //handle error second req }
})
```